# Set Post Format if find a string in title or post content

Tags: plugins, php, post-formats

I'm working with ITFFF in order to create posts, but I have a problem with the "Post Format". I need to change the Post Format to image if there are some specifics strings in the title or post content.. I was reading the forum and collecting some codes to create a this.. but it isn't working. This is my code:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'CambiarPostFormat' );

function CambiarPostFormat( $postID ) {

    $a = get_the_title( $post_id );

    if ( has_post_format( 'image', $postID ) || srtpos($a, 'imagenes') !== false)
        return;
    set_post_format( $postID, 'image' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$post_id`, but you have passed the post ID as `$postID`. As a result `$a` is always empty.

Even if it weren't empty, there is no PHP function `srtpos`. It's [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and you could have more straightforward logic to execute `set_post_format`.

Wrapping it up:

```
function CambiarPostFormat( $postID ) {

    $a = get_the_title( $postID );

    if ( !has_post_format( 'image', $postID ) && strpos($a, 'imagenes') !== false)
      set_post_format( $postID, 'image' );
    }
```

Comment: Hey man, thank you so much.. It's working right now :)